# TestNG: how NOT to ignore @Test(testName) on method-level

Tags: java, methods, annotations, testng, reportng

I'm trying to use the testName-attribute from @Test for my ReportNG html-output.

Unfortunately it says:

```
/**
* The name of the test  this test class should be placed in.  This
* attribute is ignore if @Test is not at the class level.
*/
public String testName() default "";
```

So the testName is always empty.

What needs to be changed to NOT ignore this attribute on method-level?

I'm using TestNG .xml suites to run my tests, if that's important to know.

Happy for any hint, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to specify this at the method level since the name of the test applies to the entire class.

Comment: Hello Cedric, from my understanding the name specified in the suite.xml will be shown for that test, ain't it?

What I'm trying to do is basically "abuse" the testName-attribute to pass something into my report easily. Rather then creating a new annotation/attribute I'd like to rewrite the logic for testName, so that it gets set even when used on method-level.

Thanks!

Comment: How about using `@Test(description = "the description of your test")`? This seems like a better fit for what you want than the test name. Feel freel to continue this discussion on the testng-user mailing-list, by the way.

Comment: Does not quite fit my needs, since I want both testName and testDescription to be shown in the ReportNG-Report.
Anyways, I've made a custom annotation and modified ReportNG to my needs - it was easier than expected :)